# Best way to build a custom class

Tags: beamer, document-classes, class-options

I am customizing a class based on `beamer`. In your opinion, what is the best way to define options?

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2019/03/25 myclass]
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{beamer}}
\DeclareOption{transparent}{%here some code%}
\DeclareOption{fill}{%here some code%}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{beamer}
\usetheme[progress bar = frametitle]{metropolis}
```

I want to replace the commented part of the code with something like

```
\metroset{block=transparent}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{%
 use=normal text,
 fg=normal text.fg,
 bg=normal text.bg} 
\setbeamercolor{block body}{
    use={block title, normal text},
    bg=normal text.bg}
```

and

```
\metroset{block=fill}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{%
 use=normal text,
 fg=normal text.fg,
 bg=normal text.bg!80!fg} %default normal text.bg!80!fg  
\setbeamercolor{block body}{
    use={block title, normal text},
    bg=normal text.bg!80!fg}
```

I can not put the code directly in the `DeclareOption`, since the `beamer` class and the metropolis theme are not specified yet. I can not move the `LoadClass` above, otherwise the `DeclareOption*` does not pass the options to the class. This problem can be easily solved by defining `newif`s and use as a flag to load or not load a specific part of the code. Is there a faster way to produce the same result, maybe without filling the code with many `newif`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the option code in an (internal) command like `\opt@fill`, and use `\AtEndOfClass` to execute the command ... at the end of the class.

### MWE

**myclass.cls**

```latex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2019/03/25 myclass]
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{beamer}}
\DeclareOption{transparent}{\AtEndOfClass{\opt@transparent}}
\DeclareOption{fill}{\AtEndOfClass{\opt@fill}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{beamer}
\usetheme[progress bar = frametitle]{metropolis}
\newcommand{\opt@transparent}{%
  \metroset{block=transparent}
  \setbeamercolor{block title}{%
    use=normal text,
    fg=normal text.fg,
    bg=normal text.bg} 
  \setbeamercolor{block body}{
    use={block title, normal text},
    bg=normal text.bg}}
\newcommand{\opt@fill}{%
  \metroset{block=fill}
  \setbeamercolor{block title}{%
    use=normal text,
    fg=normal text.fg,
    bg=normal text.bg!80!fg} %default normal text.bg!80!fg  
  \setbeamercolor{block body}{
    use={block title, normal text},
    bg=normal text.bg!80!fg}}
\endinput
```

**mwe.tex**

```latex
\documentclass[fill]{myclass}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{hello}
  \begin{block}{world}
    foo, bar
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**result**

[image: result]